# I made rickety tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, new-operator

I did the tic-tac-toe game but i know i can improve that. Can you give me some hints how to implement tie and keep playing as separate parts and what i can change. It my first code, dont blame me :(
I tried my best and divided the tasks into 5 functions and one main game function.

```
from random import randrange
board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, "X", 6], [7, 8, 9]]
board1 = {1: (0, 0),
          2: (0, 1),
          3: (0, 2),
          4: (1, 0),
          5: (1, 1),
          6: (1, 2),
          7: (2, 0),
          8: (2, 1),
          9: (2, 2)}


def display_board(board):
    print(f"""
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   {board[0][0]}   |   {board[0][1]}   |   {board[0][2]}   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   {board[1][0]}   |   {board[1][1]}   |   {board[1][2]}   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   {board[2][0]}   |   {board[2][1]}   |   {board[2][2]}   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+""")


def enter_move(board):
    move = int(input("Podaj liczbe na ktorej chcesz postawic O (1-9)"))
    if board1[move] in make_list_of_free_fields(board):
        a, b = board1[move]
        board[a][b] = "O"


def make_list_of_free_fields(board):
    free_fields = []
    for column in board:
        for row in column:
            if row != "X" and row != "O":
                free_fields.append(board1[row])
    return free_fields


def victory_for(board, sign):
    win_numbers = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [
        1, 5, 9], [7, 5, 3], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]
    for numbers in win_numbers:
        i = 0
        for a in numbers:
            d, e = board1[a]
            if board[d][e] == sign:
                i += 1
            if i == 3:
                print(f"Game wins the {sign} player")
                exit()
    print("tie or we keep playing")


def draw_move(board):
    draw = True
    while draw:
        k_move = randrange(1, 10)
        if board1[k_move] in make_list_of_free_fields(board):
            a, b = board1[k_move]
            board[a][b] = "X"
            draw = False


def game():
    while True:
        display_board(board)
        enter_move(board)
        victory_for(board, "O")
        display_board(board)
        draw_move(board)
        victory_for(board, "X")


game()
```

I tried so hard but i dont know how to improve it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is there a problem with the code, of which the code does not run? SO is used for error solving in code. Another forum for improving code would be more suitable for this question

Comment: Have you know any forum to improve code?

Comment: You can try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".